# HttpPost and Model Binding, what am I missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have 2 tables/classes: Films and Actors, and intermediate table relating them. I'm trying to generate a new record into the into the intermediate table to generate a new relationship and add a new film to an actor's filmography.

Here's the ViewModel class:

```
    public class ActorsUpdateFilmsViewModel
    {
        public Actor actor { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<Film> bindedFilms { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Title")]
        public int FilmId { get; set; }

        public int ActorId;
    }
```

The view where you can choose an unrelated film from a combo box:

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="right">
        <h3>Add a film:</h3>
        <form asp-action="Bind">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FilmId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="FilmId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Unbinded"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="FilmId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="actor.ActorId" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.actor" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.bindedFilms" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Bind" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the controller which retrieves data:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Bind(int id, [Bind("actor,FilmId,bindedFilms, ActorId")]ActorsUpdateFilmsViewModel model) 
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.FilmId != null)
                {
                    FilmsAndActor newBinding = new FilmsAndActor()
                    {
                        FilmIdFk = model.FilmId,
                        ActorIdFk = model.actor.ActorId
                    };
```

The newBinding item works perfectly for adding it to the intermediate table and bind the actor and the film. But the ModelState.IsValid returns a false. Why? What am I missing?

Thanks

NOTE: I have made a little test and all data is being retrieved and binded, except for the bindedFilms property. Tried to make it an IEnumerable/List, but none of these work. The .Any() function always returns a false

Comment: Break it where you're checking IsValid and see which property is causing the error.

Comment: currently none (i have run the very same code but without the IsValid and it works)

or you mean assign another value to ActorIdFk, such as model.ActorId or id and see how it works out?

Comment: If IsValid equals false then somewhere in the ModelState there's a property that is causing the issue.

Comment: What defines when it is valid or not? Not having nulls when property is defined as not nullable?

I think i must be binding wrong, maybe sending something wrong from the view,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not binding a corresponding value to `@Model.actor.ActorName` which is causing this property to receive null in the controller.

You can add a breakpoint and look at the `Values` property under `ModelState` to find which model property is `Invalid`:

[image]

There are two solutions.

The first one, add binding value to `@Model.actor.ActorName` in `UpdateFilms.cshtml`:

```
//...
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.actor.ActorName" />
//...
```

The second one, remove the `[Required]` attribute and change the `ActorName` property in the `Actor` class to be nullable:

```
[DisplayName("Actor name")]
//[Required]
public string? ActorName { get; set; } = null!;
```

Comment: It worked! Just to know: in any normal case when i pass a complex type (in this case an object "actor"), its properties will come with the binded object. The problem was that one of the actor properties, in this case, was marked as required so needed to be explicitly sent from the form, right? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if this property is required, you need to give it a value, otherwise it will be null and will not pass model validation.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have declared bindedFilms as IQueryable? It should be IEnumerable or List. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Still figuring out when is it better to use IQueryable or IEnumerable. The list is to displays actor's filmography through deferred querying in the view, but that part i didn't show it in the question because the problem is in the binding.

Anyways, already changed the property to IEnumerable and still IsValid is false

Comment: IQueryable is suitable for querying external resources (e.g. database), You need to declare api/method parameters as IEnumerable (costs less) or List, but never IQueryable. Anyway, could you provide the project or the raw html form you are submitting?

Comment: Just uploaded it to Github. Problem is in ActorsControllers, and Actors/UpdateFilms.cshtml

https://github.com/RascalSpark/FilmsWebApp/tree/master/FilmsWebApp

Comment: Thanks for uploading the code. As @Chen mentioned above. the invalid state is raised by Actor.ActorName property which has been marked as [required]. The solution would be either of the cases Chen uttered.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="actor.ActorId" />
```

Seems like you need to use @Model.ActorId.
Please also make sure that actor is not null between posts.

Comment: <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.actor.ActorId" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.actor" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.bindedFilms" />

Still IsValid returning false

Actor is not null, since the part of the view i didn't share displays the ViewModel properties and one of the actors properties (name)